# open dd menu selection in new window

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'm using the following code for a drop down menu but I want the selected option to open in a new window. How should I change this code to make this work?

```
<form name="blah_blah">
<select name="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
<option value="first_option_name" selected>option display name</option>
<option value="1st link to content">1st option name</option>
<option value="2nd link to content">2nd option name</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="top.location.href = this.form.ddmenu2.options[this.form.ddmenu2.selectedIndex].value;
return false;">
</form>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see below...

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="blah_blah">
<select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
<option value="first_option_name" selected>option display name</option>
<option value="page1.html">1st option name</option>
<option value="page2.html">2nd option name</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab')">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<html>
<body>
Page 1
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
<body>
Page 2
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you needed!!!

Good Luck!!!

**Update 1**

If you want to open new window quickly after selecting option (and not pressing Go button), below is code

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="blah_blah">
<select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;"  onChange="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'">
<option value="first_option_name" selected>option display name</option>
<option value="page1.html">1st option name</option>
<option value="page2.html">2nd option name</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```