# drop down menu: open links in new tab + "Go" link

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to have a drop down menu and

- open selected items in a new tab
- include **external** links as selection options

How should I change the following code to make it work as described above?

```
<form name="blah_blah">
<select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
<option value="first_option_name" selected>option display name</option>
<option value="external link 1">1st link name</option>
<option value="external link 2">2nd link name</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab')">
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: please also see a previous Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960981/open-dd-menu-selection-in-new-window

Comment: one question : what you mean by **include external links as selection options** What exactly you mean to say?? again you are not clear...

Comment: better explain by example....

Comment: I want users to select an option from the drop down menu, then click on "Go" and get a new tab opened in their browser, displaying their selection choice. I want the links to be external, meaning leading to a different website/page than the one where the dd menu is.

Comment: Now it clears what you want... One more question :)... When I select Option A and click `Go`, I can print "Option A" in new tab, BUT question comes here... do you want to print `Option A` in `OptionA.html`, `Option B` in `OptionB.html` and so on.... else you are OK with all options printed in `OptionA.html`? means whenever I select Any option, click `Go`, it will get printed in **ONE** html file (e.g. in `OptionA.html`).... Let me know if you are not clear with my question

Comment: I want the drop down menu to include links to other websites. e.g. option 1 linking to www.example1.com, option 2 linking to www.example2.com and so on, all opening in a new tab (after users clicking on "Go").

Comment: ok.. so If I select Option 1, it will print Option 1 in myFile1.html, If I select Option 2, it will print Option 2 in myFile2.html and so on... right??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by myfile.html etc.
Imagine a list of links:
<li><a href='URL1' target='_blank'>link 1 text</a></li>

<li><a href='URL2' target='_blank'>link 2 text</a></li>

<li><a href='URL3' target='_blank'>link 3 text</a></li>

I just want this list to be displayed as a drop down menu. Users should select their option (link text displayed to them in the list) and by clicking "Go", they get the URL in a new tab.

Comment: So your example code seems to do that. What's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="blah_blah">
            <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
                <option value="" selected>Select Site</option>
                <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!!!</option>
                <option value="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</option>
                <option value="http://www.google.co.in">Google</option>
                <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!" onClick="window.open(ddmenu_name.value,'newtab'+ddmenu_name.value)">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you need...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form name="blah_blah">
   <select name="ddmenu_name" id="ddmenu_name" style="width: 80% !important;">
      <option value="first_option_name" selected>option display name</option>
      <option value="external link 1">1st link name</option>
      <option value="external link 2">2nd link name</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var Link = $('#ddmenu_name').val();
   $('#Submit').click(function() {
      window.open(Link,'_blank');
   });
});
```

Comment: I want the code included to the input tag... Fahim's solution actually works now - Thanks a lot!